# Fatal error: Invariant violated: opaque small strings

Tags: ios, swift

```
let paths = Set([".cer", ".CER", ".crt", ".CRT", ".der", ".DER"].map { fileExtension in
        bundle.paths(forResourcesOfType: fileExtension, inDirectory: nil)
        }.joined())
```

yields during runtime

Fatal error: Invariant violated: opaque small strings

what does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This is awesome. Brace for the fix:

```
    let p = [".cer", ".crt", ".der"].map { fileExtension in
        bundle.paths(forResourcesOfType: fileExtension, inDirectory: nil)
        }
    let paths =  Set(p.joined())
```